# What is the simplest way to decompress a ZIP buffer in C#?

Tags: c#, zlib, sharpziplib

When I use **zlib** in C/C++, I have a simple method `uncompress` which only requires two buffers and no more else. Its definition is like this:

> ```
> int uncompress (Bytef *dest, uLongf *destLen, const Bytef *source,
> uLong sourceLen); 
> /*
> Decompresses the source buffer into the destination buffer.  sourceLen is    the byte length of the source buffer.  Upon entry,
> destLen is the total size    of the destination buffer, which must be
> large enough to hold the entire    uncompressed data.  (The size of
> the uncompressed data must have been saved    previously by the
> compressor and transmitted to the decompressor by some    mechanism
> outside the scope of this compression library.) Upon exit, destLen   
> is the actual size of the uncompressed data.
>
> uncompress returns Z_OK if success, Z_MEM_ERROR if there was not    enough memory, Z_BUF_ERROR if there was not enough room in the output 
> buffer, or Z_DATA_ERROR if the input data was corrupted or incomplete.
> In    the case where there is not enough room, uncompress() will fill
> the output    buffer with the uncompressed data up to that point.
> */
> ```

I want to know if C# has a similar way. I checked **[SharpZipLib FAQ](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/FAQ)** as follows but did not quite understand:

> **How do I compress/decompress files in memory?**
>
> Use a memory stream when creating the Zip stream!
>
> ```
> MemoryStream outputMemStream = new MemoryStream();
> using (ZipOutputStream zipOutput = new ZipOutputStream(outputMemStream)) {   
> // Use zipOutput stream as normal    
> ...
> ```
>
> You can get the resulting data with memory stream methods ToArray or GetBuffer.
>
> ToArray is the cleaner and easiest to use correctly with the penalty
>   of duplicating allocated memory. GetBuffer returns a raw buffer raw
>   and so you need to account for the true length yourself.
>
> See the framework class library help for more information.

I can't figure out if this block of code is for compression or decompression, if `outputMemStream` meas a compressed stream or an uncompressed stream. I really hope there is a easy-to-understand-way like in zlib. Thanks you very much if you can help me.

Comment: "This is a `DeflaterOutputStream` that writes the files into a zip archive one after another."

Comment: See this [examples](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/Zip-Samples#unpack-a-zip-with-full-control-over-the-operation). There is one using MemoryStream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [ZipArchive class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive), which I think has the features you need to accomplish in-memory decompression of zip files.

Assuming you have an array of bytes (`byte []`) which represent the ZIP file in memory, you have to instantiate a ZipArchive object which will be used to read that array of bytes and interpret them as the ZIP file you whish to load. If you check the [ZipArchive class' available constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive.-ctor) in documentation, you will see that they require a stream object from which the data will be read. So, first step would be to convert your `byte []` array to a stream that can be read by the constructors, and you can do this by using a [MemoryStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream?view=netcore-2.1) object.

Here's an example of how to list all entries inside of a ZIP archive represented in memory as a bytes array:

```
byte [] zipArchiveBytes = ...;   // Read the ZIP file in memory as an array of bytes

using (var inputStream = new MemoryStream(zipArchiveBytes))
using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(inputStream, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Listing archive entries...");
    foreach (var archiveEntry in zipArchive.Entries)
        Console.WriteLine($"   {archiveEntry.FullName}");
}
```

Each file in the ZIP archive will be represented as a [ZipArchiveEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchiveentry) instance. This class offers properties which allow you to retrieve information such as the original length of a file from the ZIP archive, its compressed length, its name, etc.

In order to read a specific file which is contained inside the ZIP file, you can use [ZipArchiveEntry.Open()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchiveentry.open). The following exemplifies how to open a specific file from an archive, if you have its [FullName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchiveentry.fullname) inside the ZIP archive:

```
ZipArchiveEntry archEntry = zipArchive.GetEntry("my-folder-inside-zip/dog-picture.jpg");
byte[] readResult;
using (Stream entryReadStream = archEntry.Open())
{
    using (var tempMemStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        entryReadStream.CopyTo(tempMemStream);
        readResult = tempMemStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

This example reads the given file contents, and returns them as an array of bytes (stored in the `byte[] readResult` variable) which you can then use according to your needs.